# Show certain HTML based off query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I have a query string that I'd like to pass into my razor view. `example.com/25?Type=1&Assigned=1`

I want to change my html based on if the query string contains certain values.  I tried doing

```
@if (Request.QueryString["Type=1&Assigned=1"])
{
  <button id="type1" class="btn-t btn-success type-button" 
onclick="SetType(1);"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>Invitation</button>
}
else {
<button id="type1" class="btn-t btn-xxxx 
type-button" onclick="SetType(1);"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"> 
</i>Invitation</button>
}
```

but it only displayed the else.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with razor views, but i'd GUESS that it'd be more like `Request.QueryString["Type"] == "1" and Request.QueryString["Assigned"]=="1"`.  You can't check the whole query string, but rather the values for each individual parameter.  EDIT: and it looks like someone beat me to the punch on an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request.QueryString` is not even `boolean` value, so  don't understand what are you donig. It is `NameValueCollection` type. If you still want to check it you should write like this:

```
@if (Request.QueryString["Type"] == "1" 
   && Request.QueryString["Assigned"] == "1")
{
...
}
```

But it's really ***bad practice*** to manipulate with `QueryString` in MVC. Use **Strongly Typed Views** and don't mess with `Request` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have to have certain classes on buttons based on what "form" they are looking at which is generated dynamically.  So I can't think of any other way to do this since the form is generated via the query string

Comment: Ah, i get it. But could be that you slould think of other way of generating form? I can't see you full case, but maby `EditorTemplates` could fit your situation? It's really messy what you're trying to do.

Comment: The obvious issue with relying on query strings is that they can be very easily manipulated by a malicious (or even just curious) end user, although I'm sure that goes without saying...